# Unpermitted parameters message in my rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my app I am creating a album to the user uploads some pictures to it.

This is my view:

```
<%= form_for @album do |f| %>
  <div class="col-9">
    <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="col-6">
        <label for="">Add or drag photos here: </label>
        <%= f.attachment_field :photos_media, multiple: true, direct: true, presigned: true %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And in my controller I have:

```
def create
  @album = current_user.albums.build(album_params)

  logger.debug("******ALBUM PARAMS*** #{album_params} ")

  if @album.save
    if params[:album][:photos_media].size > 1 
      params[:album][:photos_media][1..-1].each do |image|
        @album.photos.create(media: image, user: current_user)
      end
    end

    @photos = @album.photos
    redirect_to profile_edit_profile_albums_path
  else
    redirect_to profile_edit_profile_albums_path
  end
end

def album_params
  params.require(:album).permit(:name, :photos_media )
end
```

When I try to create a new album I got a message:

```
Unpermitted parameter: :photos_media
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Try to add the result of `logger.debug("******ALBUM PARAMS*** #{album_params} ")` What exactly is `album_params` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try add private scope like this

```
private
  def album_params
    params.require(:album).permit(:name, :photos_media)
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `photos_media` parameter is an array. If that's the case you'll need to indicate that you accept an array like this:

```
def album_params
  params.require(:album).permit(:name, photos_media: [] )
end
```